# Dependency injection: single class (WCF service) having multiple dependencies (DB repositories) how to handle?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I've read a book ["Dependency injection in .NET"](http://www.manning.com/seemann/) by Mark Seemann and it opened my eyes on many things. But still few question left. Here is one of them:

Let's say we have a WCF service exposing API for working with some database:

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    private ITableARepository _reposA;
    private ITableARepository _reposB;
    //....

    public IEnumerable<EntityA> GetAEntities()
    {
        return _reposA.GetAll().Select(x=>x.ToDTO())
    }

    public IEnumerable<EntityB> GetBEntities()
    {
        return _reposB.GetAll().Select(x=>x.ToDTO())
    }

    //...
}
```

There may be dozens of repositories service depend on. Some methods use one, some methods another, some methods use few repositories.

And my question is **how to correctly organize injection of repository dependencies into service**?

Options I see:

1. Constructor injection. Create a huge constructor with dozens of arguments. Easy for usage, but hard for managing parameters list. Also it's extreemely bad for performance as each unused repository is a waste of resources even if it doesn't use separate DB connection.
2. Property injection. Optimizes performance, but usage becomes non-obvious. How should creator of the service know which properties to initialize for specific method call? Moreover this creator should be universal for each method call and be located in the composition root. So logic there becomes very complicated and error-prone.
3. Somewhat non-standard (not described in a book) approach: create a repository factory and depend on it instead of concrete repositories. But the book say factories are very often used incorrectly as a side way to overcome problems that can be resolved much better with proper DI usage. So this approach looks suspicious for me (while achieving both performance and transparency objectives).

Or is there a conceptual problem with this relation 1 to many dependencies?

I assume the answer should differ depending on service instance context mode (probably when it's Single instance, constructor injection is just fine; for PerCall option 3 looks best if to ignore the above warning; for perSession everything depends on the session lifetime: whether it's more close to Single instance or PerCall).

If it really depends on instance context mode, then it becomes hard to change it, because change requires large changes in the code (to move from constructor injection to property injection or to repository factory). But the whole concept of WCF service ensures it is simple to change the instance context mode (and it's not so unlikely that I will need to change it). That makes me even more confused about DI and WCF combination.

Could anyone explain how this case should be resolved correctly?

Comment: You are wrong in 1. both in terms of performace and the number of arguments http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/01/20/RebuttalConstructorover-injectionanti-pattern/

Comment: @WiktorZychla, good argument. Though if we need PerCall instance context mode, and follow recommendation that SQL connection should be closed as soon as possible, we end up with creating dozens of new  repositories every time we need one. And I once saw a database with 200+ tables. Fortunately repositories are not so expensive objects to create. But doesn't it look strange from design perspective?

Comment: It isn't, I wouldn't care on how many instances are created as long as you properly close all opened connections.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> > Create a huge constructor with dozens of arguments

You should not create classes with a huge number of constructor arguments. This is the [constructor over-injection](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/01/20/RebuttalConstructorover-injectionanti-pattern/) code-smell. Having constructors with a huge amount of arguments is an indication that such class does too much: violates the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). This leads to code that is hard to maintain and extend.

> > Also it's extremely bad for performance as each unused repository is a waste of resources

Have you measured this? The amount of constructor arguments should be mainly irreverent for the performance of the application. This should not cause any noticeable difference in performance. And if it does, it becomes be time to look at the amount of work that your constructors do (since [injection constructors should be simple](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/)) or its time to switch to a faster DI container if your constructors are simple. Creating a bunch of services classes should normally be blazingly fast.

> > even if it doesn't use separate DB connection.

The constructors should not open connections in the first place. Again: they should be [simple](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/).

> > Property injection. Optimizes performance
> >     How should creator of the service know which properties to initialize for specific method call

The caller can't reliably determine which dependencies are required, since only constructor arguments are typically required. Requiring properties results in [temporal coupling](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/24/DesignSmellTemporalCoupling/) and you lose compile-time support.

Since the caller can't determine which properties are needed, all properties need to be injected and this makes the performance equivalent as with constructor injection, which -as I said- should not be a problem at all.

> > Somewhat non-standard (not described in a book) approach: create a repository factory and depend on it instead of concrete repositories.

Instead of injecting a repository factory, you could inject a *repository provider*, a pattern which is better known as the [Unit of Work pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html). The unit of work may give access to repositories.

> > I assume the answer should differ depending on service instance context mode

No, since you should never use the WCF 'Single' mode. In most cases the dependencies you inject into your WCF services are not thread-safe and should not outlive a single request. Injecting them into a singleton WCF service causes [Captive Dependencies](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/) and this is bad because it leads to all kinds of concurrency bugs.

The core problem here seems that your WCF Service classes are big and violate the Single Responsibily Principle, causing them to hard to create, maintain, and test. Fix this violation by either:

1. Splitting them up in multiple smaller classes, or
2. Moving functionality out of them into [aggregate services](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/02/RefactoringtoAggregateServices/) and apply patterns such as the [command/handler](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91) and [query/handler](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92) patterns.

Comment: I know you are correct, but I can't believe it. Some doubts still warns me. Could you clarify two points? 1. You and Wiktor voted for Constructor injection but at the same time you warned about constructor-overinjection. In combination with recommendation to split WCF service does that mean I should have separate service per repository? That looks like an awful design, hard to maintain and deploy. Look at Amazon EC2 API (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/OperationList-query.html) - it contains ~150 methods in a single WCF service - does that violate SRP? I believe no.

Comment: @OleksandrPshenychnyy: Does the Amazon API reference tell you anything about the actual class structure? How come you are so sure that those 150 methods are in the same class?

Comment: 2. It's rarely natural to make WCF service implement command/handler pattern. I have one in my current project, but the rest all use strong-typed API method separately for each query. Don't you consider this redesign as changing design to fit concrete implementation or pattern (DI)?

Comment: @OleksandrPshenychnyy: And still, if you want to have 150 methods, you can use a dispatching strategy inside that class. For instance, inject a `ICommandProcessor` and `IQueryProcessor` abstraction into your constructor. That allows you to execute commands in your business layer. That means that every method will do nothing more than map input arguments onto a command (or query) and pass the command (or query) on to the `ICommandProcessor` (or `IQueryProcessor`).

Comment: I used Amazon API and it's single WCF endpoint which contains all those methods. It's very useful to have access to all methods through single endpoint. And the responsibility of it is to manage server instances - concrete and single.

Comment: @OleksandrPshenychnyy: You don't apply the command/handler pattern to comply with DI: you these patterns to increase maintainability of your system. Your web services should expose commands and queries when your team owns the clients. When third-parties talk to your services, you need a RESTfull approach (instead of a use case approach). But when doing RESTfull, it still doesn't mean you can't use commands and queries internally.

Comment: But then CommandProcessor becomes dependent on all repositories instead of service. And in addition it should somehow decide which repository to use for each command (some big switch statement).

Comment: @OleksandrPshenychnyy: No, the `CommandProcessor` should not get all 500 command handlers injected, it should do dispatching. Take a look for instance at the `QueryProcessor` implementation from this [blog post](http://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92). It gives you a good idea of how to solve this.

Comment: Wow! You shifted my mind! I've heard and read about CQRS previously, but understood that from different perspective (reliability and scalability). Now probably I'll try this in the near future.
Thank you very much!